# Is it a good way to use java.util.List as a buffer?

Tags: java, list, size

I have the main **process** and a **thread** running together.
The main process receives all the incoming UDP messages and put it into a List.

Then the thread is intended for processing those UDP messages.

However when I tried the following snippet inside the thread

```
int count = 0;
while(true)
{
    if (buffer.size()>count)
    {
        System.out.println("Processing "+buffer.get(count));
        count++;
    }
}
```

the thread doesn't seem to work well.

By the way, *buffer* is

```
List<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and it is where the main process puts all the received UDP messages

any advice guys? :-)

Comment: The thread loops forever.

Comment: first, why do you want the while to run endlessly? you have while(true), so the thread will never end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is the classic purpose of a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29), and you probably want some implementation of [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Comment: here's a good example for a `BlockingQueue`.
[Java BlockingQueue Example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html#java-blockingqueue-example)

Answer (score 2):

Your thread is using [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), which explains why it doesn't work well. When the list is empty, the thread consumes all the CPU resources it can. You want the opposite: as long as the queue is empty, the thread should do nothing.

There are several ways of designing this. The basic behavior is known as [the producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). The easiest approach to implementing it in Java is to use a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), although it's easy enough to implement your own wait/notify protocol on a basic `List`. I believe the Wikipedia article shows how to do this in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Without some sort of synchronization, it is surely not a good idea to use shared resources this way. I am assuming no synchronization as I don't see any code for it.

Given the code you have, the while loop will never terminate and I can only imagine the buffer will continue to grow before you run out of memory.

Java provides specific data structures for implementations that you have described. You can consider looking into [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

Comment: This was my first thought. Thank you for verifying it. Now I can live in peace. [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) seems to be a good solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are parsing a String protocol, use a queue instead.

If you are parsing bytes, look into using [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) as its bulk operations will be more efficient for buffering.

In either case you'll likely need to ensure thread safety through synchronous structures.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it looks like you have a syntactically incorrect typo (counter++). I'm going to assume that you meant (count++).

The solution to your problem is a [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) not a List. In particular you will want to use the [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) for this application.